# Can I bag wrap my suitcase at Leeds railway station?

Tags: trains, uk, luggage

I want to take 2 suitcases, one inside the other but the zip won't zip up.  My local airport does not offer a bag wrap service and I wondered if I could do this at Leeds railway station before my flight.  Anyone done this?

Comment: I've never seen bag wrapping at any UK railway station, so I fear you'd be out of luck. Is simply buying a new outer suitcase an option?

Answer (score 2):

[The Excess Baggage Company](http://www.left-baggage.co.uk/) has [an outlet at Leeds Station](http://www.left-baggage.co.uk/locations.php), and they're about the only company likely to, as they do wrap at other locations, but generally only airports.

If you click 'more info' on their [locations page for North Britan rail stations](http://www.left-baggage.co.uk/locations.php), for Leeds you'll see:

```
Leeds Station
Left Luggage Office, Main Concourse, Leeds Station, Leeds, LS1 4DY
Telephone: 0113 243 8030
Email: Leeds@excess-baggage.com

Opening Hours
Monday to Sunday 07:00 - 23:00

Services
• Baggage Storage
• Worldwide Baggage Shipping
• UK and Ireland Domestic Baggage Delivery
• Lost Property/ Lost and found
• Courier and Parcel Shipping

Left Luggage Rates
£3.00 per Item     0 - 3hrs
£5.00 per Item     3 - 6hrs
£7.00 per Item     6 - 24hrs
```

So unfortunately, that particular location doesn't have it. However, I'd still suggest going to them and asking - they are the most likely to know where and if it's possible in the local area.

Comment: Wrong! the bag wrap service is only available in airports, not in rail stations. Click on more info in the [link](http://www.left-baggage.co.uk/locations.php) you provided and you will see the "bag wrap" service is only listed under airports...

Comment: @HaLaBi well spotted, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

[The Left Baggage Service](http://www.left-baggage.co.uk/left_luggage_leeds.php) usually provides this kind of service and I have seen that in London Euston. You can call them to find out.